# How can I store multiple function as a value of the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, partial

In the following code I try to store multiple functions as a value of the dictionary. This code doesn't work. The two functions are returned as a tuple. But I don't want to iter over the dictionary. I want to use a special key, and then I want the dictionary to run the two functions.

```
from functools import partial

def test_1(arg_1 = None):
     print "printing from test_1 func with text:", arg_1

def test_2(arg_2 = None):
     print "printing from test_2 func with text:", arg_2

dic = {'a':(partial(test_1, arg_1 = 'test_1'),
            partial(test_2, arg_2 = 'test_2'))}

dic['a']()
```

Comment: Define a third function to go in the dictionary that calls the other two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a closure to do that like:

#### Code:

```
def chain_funcs(*funcs):
    """return a callable to call multiple functions"""
    def call_funcs(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)

    return call_funcs
```

#### Test Code:

```
def test_1(arg_1=None):
    print("printing from test_1 func with text: %s" % arg_1)


def test_2(arg_2=None):
    print("printing from test_2 func with text: %s" % arg_2)


from functools import partial
dic = {'a': chain_funcs(partial(test_1, arg_1='test_1'),
                        partial(test_2, arg_2='test_2'))}

dic['a']()
```

#### Results:

```
printing from test_1 func with text: test_1
printing from test_2 func with text: test_2
```

Comment: First, thank you for your help. I am a Python beginner. So my goal is to learn and understand your source code. I edited my question and you will find many print-statements and comments. At one point in your source code, I asked a question in the comment, right after STEP 10.

Comment: Please do not ask more questions in a question.  The point of Stackoverlfow, is not to solve your problems, but to gather a collections of questions and answers  If you confuse your question with more questions, then this does not work.  Please ask another question if you don't understand something as a followup to your original question.  But as a hint, you should investigate `partial` which came from your question.